# Java Shipping cost calculator

Tags: java

I'm working on a shipping cost calculator and I have it all written but I have 1 little problem.  I need to charge x amount for every 500 miles.  It works but if the miles are a multiple of 500 it tacks on another charge for another 500 miles.  I understand why it does that with the way I've written it but I don't know how else to get say 750 miles to to get 2 charges for the first 500 miles and then the rest.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This program will ask you to enter the weight\n" +"of your package and how many miles it will travel.\n" +"It will then calculate the shipping cost for you.","Greeting",1);

    String weight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the weight of your package in pounds such as 5.25.", "Weight", 1);
    Double weightnum = Double.parseDouble(weight);
    Double overweight = weightnum-10;

    String miles = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "You have entered " +weightnum +" lbs.\n" +"Please enter in whole numbers how many miles your package needs to travel such as 250.", "Distance", 1);
    int milesnum = Integer.parseInt(miles);
    if (milesnum <500)
    {
        milesnum=0;
    }

    Double cost;
    if (weightnum < 2)
    {
        cost = (milesnum/500+1)*1.10;
    }
    else if (weightnum < 6)
    {
        cost = (milesnum/500+1)*2.50;
    }
    else if (weightnum < 10)
    {
        cost = (milesnum/500+1)*3.90;
    }
    else 
    {
        cost = (milesnum/500+1)*(4.00+(overweight*.5));
    }

    String strcost= String.format("%.2f", cost);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It will cost $" +strcost +" to ship your " +weightnum +" lbs package " +miles +" miles.\n" +"Have a nice day!", "Cost", 1);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Math.ceil`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)):

> **Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer**. Special cases:
>
> - If the argument value is already equal to a mathematical integer, then the result is the same as the argument.
> - If the argument is NaN or an infinity or positive zero or negative zero, then the result is the same as the argument.
> - If the argument value is less than zero but greater than -1.0, then the result is negative zero.

```
cost = Math.ceil(milesnum/500.0)*multiplier;
```

The expression `milesnum/500.0` will return a double (as opposed to `milesnum/500`, which will return an int). `math.ceil` will then round that value up.

If `milesnum == 500`, `milesnum/500.0` is 1, which is rounded to 1.

If `milesnum == 550`, `milesnum/500.0` is 1.1, which is rounded to 2.

Comment: Ok I got it.  I had tried the Math.ceil before but I didn't change the 500 to 500.0.  Thanks!